# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: NULL index table key value ORA-06512: at "OJC.JC_MASTER", line 129

Tags: plsql, oracle12c, oracle-data-integrator

I'm trying to run an interface in ODI 11g. When I call the procedure I get this error :

> ODI-1228: Task START_JC (Procedure) fails on the target ORACLE connection OJC.
>   Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: NULL index table key value
>   ORA-06512: at "OJC.JC_MASTER", line 129
>   ORA-06512: at "OJC.JC_MASTER", line 689
>   ORA-06512: at line 9

the sql code

```
 PROCEDURE string_to_aa_parameter_type (
   p_string                             VARCHAR2,
   p_out_aa_parameter_values   IN OUT   aa_parameter_type
)
AS
   v_start                  INTEGER         := 1;
   v_pos                    INTEGER         := 0;
   v_counter                INTEGER         := 0;
   v_temp_parameter_name    VARCHAR2 (4000);
   v_temp_parameter_value   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
   IF p_string IS NULL
   THEN
      RETURN;
   END IF;

   -- determine first chuck of string
   v_pos := INSTR (p_string, '=', v_start);

   -- while there are chunks left, loop
   WHILE (v_pos != 0)
   LOOP
      v_counter := v_counter + 1;

      -- create array
      IF MOD (v_counter, 2) = 1
      THEN
         v_temp_parameter_name :=
                               SUBSTR (p_string, v_start, v_pos - v_start);
         v_start := v_pos + 1;
         v_pos := INSTR (p_string, ';', v_start);
      ELSE
         v_temp_parameter_value :=
                               SUBSTR (p_string, v_start, v_pos - v_start);

         p_out_aa_parameter_values (trim(v_temp_parameter_name)) :=
                                                    trim(v_temp_parameter_value);

         v_start := v_pos + 1;
         v_pos := INSTR (p_string, '=', v_start);

      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   -- IN THE FOLLOWING LINE I GET THE ERROR 
   v_temp_parameter_value := SUBSTR (p_string, v_start);

   p_out_aa_parameter_values (trim(v_temp_parameter_name)) :=
                                             trim(v_temp_parameter_value);

END;
```

Can someone help me in figuring out that the problem is ?

Comment: How are you calling it, and what are you passing in? And are you sure it's that line and not the next one, which woudl make more sense for the error; `v_temp_parameter_name` seems to end up null, so is the value you're giving for `p_string` not null but with no equals sign?

Comment: yes the error comes from the last line . i didn't write the procedure,i have to run it . It is supposed to be syntax correct .

Comment: Syntactically correct doesn't mean logically correct or complete. It doesn't seem to be expecting to have to handle the data you're actually sending it. That doesn't even necessarily means it's wrong or broken - whoever did write it might say your code is the problem not theirs. Depends on the agreed specification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get that error if `p_string` is a not-null value which doesn't contain an equals sign at all, or with any semicolon-delimited part that starts with an equals sign. It's thrown by the line after the one you indicated (or the equivalent line inside the loop, if `p_string` has a final semicolon).

If there is no equals sign at all then

```
v_pos := INSTR (p_string, '=', v_start);
```

gives zero, which means you don't go through the loop at all; which means when you get to that final assignment `v_temp_parameter_name` has never been set.

If there is a key/value pair with no key, say `p_string` is `'x=y;=z'` you do go into the loop, and with that example the first key/value pair is added to the array; but then `v_start` and `v_pos` end up as the same value (5 in this case, both pointing to the second `=`). The the next time round the loop:

```
         v_temp_parameter_name :=
                               SUBSTR (p_string, v_start, v_pos - v_start);
```

evaluates to `SUBSTR(p_string, 5, 0)` (where the third argument is zero because those two variables are the same), which is always going to be an empty string, or null.

There is no actual error yet, so it evaluates `v_pos` again, and either gets zero or non-zero, depending on whether there is a terminating semicolon.

If it's non-zero then it goes round the loop again; if it's zero it drops out. Either way it has a last stab at getting the matching value - it doesn't matter if that is set to anything or not. When it tries to add the element to the array, though, the name is still null, and you get that error, from whichever of the two array assignments it hits.

You could do additional testing and handling inside the procedure to spot and discard null keys, but

> i didn't write the procedure,i have to run it . It is supposed to be syntax correct

So you need to figure out why the Java code is passing a value which the procedure can't handle - i.e. why it is sending incomplete key/value pairs.

Comment: i have to find out how to fix the error without changing the code. Im getting the followin error 

> ORA-20000: S:Server - javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[14,385]
Message: Attribute name &quot;PRM&quot; associated with an element type &quot;STARTUP&quot; must be followed by the &apos; = &apos; character.]

Comment: @eda - that error doesn't seem to be coming from the code you posted. Are you calling something this calls that procedure and converts the array into XML? It still looks like a data problem, you need to see what is actually being send for `p_string`.

Comment: yes exactly thats what im trying to do . This is an Interface ,to run it im calling another ODI Project which has this procedure.

Comment: The issue still seems to be what is in `p_string` though. Without knowing what you're putting in that, or how it's being generated if you aren't providing it directly, I'm not sure how you can proceed. And we can't see the steps involved or where the data/values are coming from.

Comment: i fix it by calling another procedure before this . thanks thought